# Clicking sound and error HGST 12TB

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a problem with my HGST 12TB buy recently to backup my 3 external hard drive 4tb toshiba canvio basic.
When i copy from all my 3 external Hard drive (one by one not all in the same time) to my HGST and that copy is more than 500gb of data the HGST make a clinking sound after the copy, it does not make the sound if is less than 500gb. My Hgst is put in Ugreen External enclosure 3.5 and i use a HUB USB with power supply (my laptop has only 1 usb 3.0 port) to copy from ONLY one toshiba
to my HGST (there is only 2 device connected to this HUB no more). This issue never occur when copying between 2 toshiba connect with this USB HUB

There is more when i copy more than 500gb of data between my 2 external hard drive there is randomly the Error 0x80070079: The semaphore timeout period has expired occur and my HGST is always to 100% activity response not the toshiba, this slows down my PC and to resolve that i need to unplug my HGST without eject because eject doesn't work because of this activity.
This error never occur when copying between 2 toshiba connect with this USB HUB

I try between my PC and my HGST with and without the USB hub but my hard drive inside my PC is a Samsung SSD 512gb with 4OOGB of data but with this i have no issue to copy this data to my HGST

Crystaldiskinfo tell me that all my hard drive is good with zero problem

I don t have any other PC than my laptop to test but with this information can you tell me is my hard drive is failing or it is my enclosure or HUB usb are faulty

Thank you (sorry for my english i'm not a native english speaker)

Laptop: Sony Vaio SVE1512T1ESI with SSD 512GB Samsung
Hardrive: WD Ultrastar HUH721212ALE604 and toshiba canvio basic 4tb
Enclosure (https://www.ugreen.com/products/3-5-usb-3-0-hard-drive-enclosure)
Hub USB with power supply (Maketech 7-port Rotatable USB 3.0 HUB)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as if the 12 TB disk is getting too hot when copying a lot of data in a single run.
The disk probably locks up itself to prevent further overheating. After it has a chance to cool down it will work again.
When you copy smaller amounts of data and wait a couple of minutes between each copy you will probably not have any problems.

Such USB enclosures are known for causing this kind of problems because they don't have any active cooling. (The disk transfers its operating heat to the metal housing of the enclosure itself and the ambient air cools the housing but that is quite inefficient.)

Putting the enclosure in the airflow of a desk-fan might help to keep it cooler.

Personally I have given up on enclosures completely for heavy duty copying precisely because of this issue.
I always use either a USB3 SATA docking station or a SATA to USB convertor-cable. And just plug in the naked harddisk.
Makes swapping the harddisk much easier (I have several drives) and has way better cooling because there is no enclosure getting in the way.

Comment: I would agree that the problem is the enclosure rather than the HDD.  Of course the health of the HDD could be the problem.  Any application that displayed the S.M.A.R.T data would help diagnose that problem. While temperature is one of those field in the S.M.A.R.T it wouldn't be accurate in a case like this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response  I forgot to specify that i left open the enclosure (i don't put the upper panel) because of the heat.
At the end of heavy transfert my disk heat is 49° celsius or 120° fahrenheit but i will try to buy like you say a Sata to usb directly

Comment: Please reply in _comments_ section under answers. This post was posted as a separate answer, so it will be deleted.